# Wix installer with more MSI. How to do it?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

According to this question ([How should I handle product upgrades in a WiX installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483055/how-should-i-handle-product-upgrades-in-a-wix-installer)) I want to split my big MSI file into 2 or more smaller file in order to have smaller update.

How can I implement Micro-packages with WIX?
Any tutorial, article or link is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WiX 3.6 (Beta) has a new bootstrapper called "Burn".  You can read about it here:

[Building Installation Package Bundles](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm)

Comment: Ok but what's comes before the bootstrapper. Should I create a Wix project for every MSI? Is there a way to create more MSI form a single WIX project?

Comment: There are ways of using preprocessor variables in your wxs and passing different values into the compiler to get installer variants but I doubt that's what you need.  You probably want to break your installer out into fragments and then create 2 wix projects that reference in different sets of fragments and define didn't product specific properties.  It's hard to give you an answer without seeing your entire source.

Comment: Basically what I have right now is few dlls and a lot of media files. All of them are in the same msi. I want to distribute trough a Major Update the new dlls version without give the unchanged media files. According to your reply I have to create 2 wix project: 1 for dlls and 1 for media. For the first distribution I will use a bootstrapper to merge the msi, for the update I will distribute only  the dlls MSI. It seems Ok for me!

Comment: This isn't optimal for all situations, but the bootstrapper also has the ability to download MSI's on demand at install time.  This always you to ship a <1MB EXE that then does the rest.  However this is annoying in corp environments where internet access isn't wanted for deploying to 10,000 machines.   There are ways for the Sys Admin to forcibly download and cache the MSI's but it's a PITA IMO.